# What legal strategy might be applied to successfully sue private companies over their own mask rules?

Tags: united-states, civil-law

I asked recently about [the mask rules in airports](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/74329/608), but in my travels recently I'm more baffled that private companies are requiring masks under threat of refused service, and even permanent refusal into the future. Primarily, I've noticed some airlines advertise their own mask rules that customers must agree to, and the taxi apps (eg Uber, Lyft) make you actually check a box "I am wearing a mask" before you can call a ride. Apparently I broke the rule add the driver pulled up, and he must have alerted the company, who in turn threatened to ban me permanently from their service if I did it again.

I personally think these corporate rules are dubious, especially when use of their services is in an area where no such government orders are in place. I figure there must be some limits on "dress codes" or other non-covid justifications they might come up with.

Under the circumstances, I understand why, but I've heard many times a judge argue
in his jurisprudence that circumstances cannot justify any actions otherwise illegal, so thus laws would have to be changed first.

So, I expect eventually someone will sue a company over its mask rules, but what legal argument would they likely give?

Comment: Have you heard “no shirt no shoes - no service” or noticed little signs that say “We reserve the right to refuse service to anyone” ? This is freedom - the freedom to contract, as Trish answers. Formally worshiped by conservatives.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite If you're going to turn this political, you'll earn an unfriendly flag from me. I'm not interested in your signaling.

Comment: Are you expecting that some valid legal arguments must exist against something merely because you think it is dubious?

Comment: @Greendrake Not at all. Just hoping for legally creative answers. Just something I've been thinking about, as a casual law student.

Comment: And perhaps that cases haven't arisen yet because intolerance for the action is not yet too much for someone with the means and willingness.

Comment: @608. My opinion is that your initial question betrayed a political bent since it is typically conservatives who presume there must be a reason company’s can’t set a COVID policy for themselves. In other contexts, conservatives typically have sided with company’s being free to set rules for whom they deal with. I should have said that in a straightforward manner if I was to express that thought.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Any political bent is surely read in. Both sides complain aplenty about exactly the same things, but seemingly only when they don't like the outcomes. In the case of conservatives complaining about masks, they also complained much about cakes, yet those are contradicting opinions, mostly.

Comment: I'm really just interested in the weird (legally creative) ways such people might work against this. Like 1A against the cake problem.

Comment: @608 I agree that no side is really consistent in the logic of its positions.

Comment: I suggest that there are no viable legal strategies for this, only political ones, similar to the 2020 Presidential election lawsuits.

Comment: What is the "cake problem"?

Comment: @JosephP. Some years ago an American Christian baker didn't want to make a personalized wedding cake for a gay couple, though did offer generic, pre-made cakes. The couple sued, and the baker won based mostly on the religion and "free expression" portions of the First Amendment argument.

Comment: @608, actually the baker did not win on the underlying issue. The Supreme Court overturned the ruling against him on the grounds that he did not get a fair hearing, the commission was biased against religious reasons, the Court said. The decision left it possible for the case to be re-brought with a fair hearing, but that was never done. We don't kn ow how a similar case with a fair hearing would come out.

Answer (score 9):

### None because the principle is Freedom to contract

There is a general right of any being (natural like a person or even a company) to contract with anyone. Buying someone's service is a contract.

A contract forms when:

- They offer something
- You offer something
- **Both** sides agree on it. (*meeting of the minds*)

It is totally legal for a company to make *wears a mask in our place of business* a part of either being admitted onto the property or agreeing to contract with you.
Noncompliance means as a result that they don't agree to serve you and don't offer to you. In fact, they explicitly [**reject**](https://www.upcounsel.com/rejection-in-contract-law) to contract with you unless you wear a mask, which is their right **unless** there is a law that would specifically make that reason illegal.

There are laws that reduce the freedom of contract, such as the civil right act (protected classes, such as religion, race, sex and more), the Americans with disabilities act (demanding *reasonable accommodation*), and labor laws (outlawing labor practices or limiting the amount of work or minimum payment) as well as anti-discrimination laws (establishing further classes).

However note, that laws need to be written in such a way that they don't discriminate against the company either! One case where freedom to contract was attacked using an anti-discrimination law was [Masterpiece Cakeshop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masterpiece_Cakeshop_v._Colorado_Civil_Rights_Commission) - which was decided on first amendment grounds based on the rights of the owner: the law can't force someone to make a product he would not support the message of.

Currently, there might only be some ordinance that bans mask policies in Texas, but it is dubious if that might be even an enforceable order from the Texas governor - Especially since [OSHA](https://www.osha.gov/coronavirus/standards) just made adjustments to standards and mandates on the federal level - which include adjustments to respiratory protection fields.

Comment: See West Coast Hotel Co. v. Parrish et seq.

Comment: @user6726 that was a **minimum wage** case of 1937 - irrelevant to the topic. There *was* law that made the contracts sought by the hotel illegal. Here there is no law in most of the states. In general, the question is about hiring a company that doesn't want to be hired unless you do X, making it more akin to Masterpiece Cakeshop.

Comment: Apparently you are not aware of the history of how freedom of contract was overturned in the US. Look at the big picture, not the specific holdings.

Comment: @user6726 in the department of "Customer buying service" it is still the guiding principle: unless a contract is illegal, it is valid.

Comment: Are there no laws using squirrelly language, like "decency" or "reasonable"?

Comment: @608 Reasonable means 'within reason'. For example, trying to go maskless via the "reasonable accommodation" in the ADA, (which is not applicable to the general public!) would need you to prove that you can't wear a mask for medical reasons (Religion is not a disability!). Now, an accommodation could take the shape of a transport that does have separate compartments, but that can't be installed on the fly, is far more expensive than the single fare and thus is not a reasonable accommodation. In fact, there might be no reasonable accommodation in this example.

Comment: @Trish Sorry for coming back late. WRT "reasonable", pre-covid I'm pretty confident virtually everyone would call "masks for public health" in restaurants, planes, and taxis "unreasonable". The idea of covering your face was offensive, and even considered a security issue. That's why I brought up "circumstances cannot justify any actions otherwise illegal". Pre-covid, surely there'd have been lawsuits. Now that rules are finally waning, if major places continue with it, we should expect lawsuits, no?

Comment: @608 Have you ever entered the premises of a workshop working with heavy machinery to buy a specialty tool or part? Like a workshop that works with lumber? "Helmet and safety shoes have to be worn at all times" is very common beyond the sales area, and in some industry suppliers even *there* it can exist. Prescribed safety gear to even access the place to try to negotiate a deal is very common.

Comment: @Trish I've always understood that to be an extension of osha. A regulation, not a company choice.

Comment: To extend it to the sales floor is a company choice.

Answer (score 3):

> I personally think these corporate rules are dubious, especially when use of their services is in an area where no such government orders are in place. I figure there must be some limits on "dress codes" or other non-covid justifications they might come up with.

The law does not agree with you. There are no such limitations (but some states have recently attempted to adopt such regulations by executive order, such as Florida). The attempts to impose such limitations have mostly been struck down by the courts.

For example, a corporate covid vaccination policy of United Airlines was [recently upheld in the face of a court challenge](https://www.npr.org/2021/11/09/1053814689/united-airlines-vaccine-mandate-religious-exemption-court-sued).

Comment: The upholding of the United vaccination policy is striking, but very different in a few ways. First, it involves employment. Second, it's vaccines (which to my mind is much more personally invasive than masks, so the ruling surprises me). I wonder how the judge rules "forced unpaid leave" as not causing harm, yet chastised United for "apathy, if not antipathy," for their employees. Maybe I need a new question on "harm".

Answer (score 1):

The question reads:

> I personally think these corporate rules are dubious, especially when use of their services is in an area where no such government orders are in place. I figure there must be some limits on "dress codes" or other non-covid justifications they might come up with.

You figure incorrectly. Under US laws, businesses are generally free to determine who they will do business with, and under what conditions, subject to anti-descrimnaion laws and other valid laws. "non-mask-wearers" is not a protected class under any such law to date. A state could pass such a law, requiring a business to serve those who refuse to wear masks in spite of business policies. No US state has yet done so. In a few states governors have attempted to create such rules by Executive Order, but those attempts have largely been voided by the courts.

Comment: What is the basis again for reconciling anti discrimination with freedom to contract (or not)?

Comment: @Joseph P "freedom of Contract" is always subject to current laws. A conrsact to comit a crime si not binding or lawful. A contract that violates a law or regulation, such as a limit on working hours, or an anti-discrimination provision, is in many cases void. Landlord/tenant law often specifies certain legal duties which may not be waived or modified by the terms of a lease. In fact even offering a lease which purports to waive such laws may be a crime in itself. So "freedom of contract" is generally subordinate to current law. [...]

Comment: [...] @Joseph P Back in the  there were several decisions of the US Supreme court which elevate "freedom of contract" into a ruling constitutional right. These decisions struck down regulations of workign hours and conditions as violations of  "freedom of contract". These decisions were all overruled in the later 1930s, and are no longer good law. Indeed they helped give "substantive due process" a very bad name in legal circles.

Comment: Okay, so a tenancy lease in which a tenant, secretly knowing their rights,  deceptively entering into a contract with a greedy landlord who is hopelessly ignorant and apathetic of the laws that contains terms favouring the landlord but which are statutorily unfair and unenforceable which the landlord may not have agreed to the contract without would still go by the statutorily prescribed terms despite this seemingly fundamentally important "meeting of the minds"?

Comment: What is substantive due process in this context?

Comment: David I think you might have missed a little word or so.

Comment: @Joseph P Yes I did, sorry, that should have read "back in the 1920s nd early 1930s there were..."

Comment: @Joseph P " substantive due process" is the idea that certain actual rules of law, not merely procedural requirements, are implied by the "Due process Clause" of the 5tyh and 14th amendments to the US constitution. The cases that struck down labor regulations, including minimum wage laws, unemployment compensation laws, and maxim hour laws in the service of "freedom of contract"  are generally considered examples of " substantive due process" and are now disfavoresd by the US courts

Comment: So it’s the idea that substantive due process means that the constitution itself entitles one to due process of law in the sense of process which not merely follows all of the normal rules of judicial procedure, but that actually also considers all of the applicable legal statutes which are currently in effect, even… those which may arguably be unconstitutional?? Seeming to thereby elevate every effective legal statute to a position of importance on par with the actual constitution itself?

Comment: It seems a like circular/tautological/meaningless as far as I’ve been able to understand it from your comment, but thanks nonetheless.

Comment: @Joseph P The right to Due Process traditionally refers to a right to have things done in  a proper way: No search w'out a warrant; no arrest w'out probable cause; no conviction w'out a fair jury ttial ; no confession w'out a Miranda warning; no lawsuit without proper notice served, etc. "substantive due process " is when courts find a rule on **what** should be done, not just **how** it should be done to be included in the right to Due process. [...]

Comment: @Joseph P [...]  The "incorporation" of the bill of rights into he 14th amendment is an example of substantive due process. So is the right to interracial marriage found in *Loving vs Virginia* So were many of the "freedom of Contract" cases.